# Why is attribute 'sortable' disappearing in <th>-tag generated by html-helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I will create a table with a header that looks like:

```
<th field="id" formatter="" styler="" sortable="true">#Asset</th>
```

For this, I use this code

```
$this->Html->tag('th',#Asset,'field'=>'id', [
    'formatter'=>'',
    'styler'=>'',
    'sortable'=>'true'
]);
```

but stangely, I get this as a result:

```
<th field="id" formatter="" styler="" sortable="sortable">#Asset</th>
```

If I change the code

```
$this->Html->tag('th',#Asset,'field'=>'id', [
    'formatter'=>'',
    'styler'=>'',
    'sortable'=>''
]);
```

the result is even stranger, the attribute 'sortable' disappears:

```
<th field="id" formatter="" styler="">#Asset</th>
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortable` is/was a [**boolean attribute**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes). Such an attributes `false` state is represented by not defining the attribute, and its `true` state is represented by either an empty value, or the name of attribute. The actual values `true` or `false` are not valid for boolean attributes.

For backwards/cross-browser compatibility, CakePHP uses the latter value variant. Passing `false`-ish values (such as an empty string) to the HTML helper will cause the attribute to not be added.

ps. `sortable` has been [**removed from the HTML standard**](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/56) last year, it's not present in the current HTML 5.1 recommendiations anymore.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\View\StringTemplate::formatAttributes()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.View.StringTemplate.html#_formatAttributes)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\StringTemplate::$_compactAttributes](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.View.StringTemplate.html#$_compactAttributes)**

Comment: Ok, that makes things clear for me. 
Is there a workaround for the use of this attribute because it is used in a jquery-script for a datagrid?

Comment: Don't use the HTML helper, or use an extended templater (configurable via the helpers `templateClass` option) that removes `sortable` from the compact attributes list, or fix the jQuery script so that it handles boolean attributes correctly.